# getting : java.sql.SQLException: Unknown system variable 'language' spring boot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am beginning with spring data jpa and i have configured all spring app. in which my bootstrap class is

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.ticket.booking")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.ticket.booking.dao")
@EntityScan("com.ticket.booking.entity")
public class TicketBookingManagementApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(TicketBookingManagementApplication.class, args);
}
```

}

my controller

```
 @RestController
 @RequestMapping(value="/api/ticket")
 public class TicketController {

@Autowired
private TicketService ticketService;



@GetMapping(value="/")
public String welcome(){
    return "Welcome to Ticket Booking Systems";
}

@PostMapping(value="/add")
public Ticket createTicket(@RequestBody Ticket ticket){
    return ticketService.createNewTicket(ticket);
}

@GetMapping(value="/get/{ticketId}")
public Ticket getTicket(@PathVariable ("ticketId") Integer ticketId){

    return ticketService.getTicketById(ticketId);
}
```

}

service and repository

```
 @Service
 public class TicketService {


@Autowired
private TicketDao ticketDao;


public Ticket createNewTicket(Ticket ticket) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return ticketDao.save(ticket);
}


public Ticket getTicketById(Integer ticketId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return ticketDao.findOne(ticketId);
}


}


public interface TicketDao extends CrudRepository<Ticket, Integer>{}
```

in pom.xml i have added

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

It uses  `mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46` and it maps req successfully but while running app i am getting error like

```
  java.sql.SQLException: Unknown system variable 'language'
```

and exporting schema to database

Comment: Give your mysql version

Comment: mysql version 5.1.30

Comment: can you provide the configuration detail for mysql

Comment: Provide your configuration properties in question

Comment: @Vishal Kawade check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update your mysql-connector version. it will solve your problem.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>mysql</groupId>
<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
<version>5.1.35</version>
```

properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/schema_name
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this answer because somebody might get benefited from this.

In my case, I was working with Spring-boot so the dependency in pom.xml was

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

So spring boot was taking some default dependency version from Spring boot parent which was different from my System installed mysql-server version 5.1.22 so that was the reason behind that error.

So to resolve this error I overridden the version by specifying manually like below.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.22</version>
</dependency>
```

and it worked.